# XPath find element if children element contains text

Tags: html, xpath, xpath-2.0

Say I have the following elements

```
<div class="someDiv">
   <p class="someP">1</p>
   <span class="someP">2</span>
   <h1 class="someP">3</h1>
</div>
<div class="someDiv">
   <p class="someP">4</p>
   <span class="someP">5</span>
   <h1 class="someP">6</h1>
</div>
```

I want to find the div that has any child elements that contain text '1' or '3' (which means the first div). I can search on any text (which the elements are not known so it needs to be dynamic - I used span, h1 and p tags as an example but they could be other tags).

tried using ancestor and sibling but could not find a way to find the parent div element

Answer (score 0):

```
//div[//*[contains(text(), "1") or contains(text(), "3")]]
```

Comment: This will also match an element whose value is "101" or "321": which is what the OP asked for, but I doubt it is what they actually wanted. I suspect a more suitable answer is` //div[.//*[. = '1' or .='3']]`

Comment: Yes, this was it. @MichaelKay